# jstree - rename functionality issue (text input on node, after clicking rename, does not accept changes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jstree

I am using jquery.jstree plugin and the only problem is that after right clicking on a node and renaming it, the text input box is opened to let me enter the new name. Then I type the new name but the text input's value is not changing, it is like frozen. If I press the enter button it posts the same text to the server but I am not able to modify the value in the text input.

I reproduced the issue on both firefox and chrome. There is no alert or error message on js console.

Additionally when I focused on the tree, other inputs are not working also like tab button, ctrl+f5 etc.

Any idea about the issue?

My jstree code is as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tree-container")
        .bind("before.jstree", function (e, data) {
            $("#alog").append(data.func + "<br />");
        })
        .jstree({
            // List of active plugins
            "plugins": [
                "themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "cookies", "dnd", "search", "types", "contextmenu"
            ],

            // I usually configure the plugin that handles the data first
            // This example uses JSON as it is most common
            "json_data": {
                // This tree is ajax enabled - as this is most common, and maybe a bit more complex
                // All the options are almost the same as jQuery's AJAX (read the docs)
                "ajax": {
                    // the URL to fetch the data
                    "url": "/backoffice/categorytree/getchildren",
                    // the `data` function is executed in the instance's scope
                    // the parameter is the node being loaded 
                    // (may be -1, 0, or undefined when loading the root nodes)
                    "data": function (n) {
                        // the result is fed to the AJAX request `data` option
                        return {
                            "ParentCategoryId": n.attr ? n.attr("id").replace("node_", "") : 1
                        };
                    }
                }
            },
            // Configuring the search plugin
            "search": {
                // As this has been a common question - async search
                // Same as above - the `ajax` config option is actually jQuery's AJAX object
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/backoffice/categorytree/search",
                    // You get the search string as a parameter
                    "data": function (str) {
                        return {
                            "SearchString": str
                        };
                    }
                }
            },
            // Using types - most of the time this is an overkill
            // read the docs carefully to decide whether you need types
            "types": {
                // I set both options to -2, as I do not need depth and children count checking
                // Those two checks may slow jstree a lot, so use only when needed
                "max_depth": -2,
                "max_children": -2,
                // I want only `drive` nodes to be root nodes 
                // This will prevent moving or creating any other type as a root node
                "valid_children": ["drive"],
                "types": {
                    // The default type
                    "default": {
                        // I want this type to have no children (so only leaf nodes)
                        // In my case - those are files
                        "valid_children": "none",
                        // If we specify an icon for the default type it WILL OVERRIDE the theme icons
                        "icon": {
                            "image": "http://www.jstree.com/static/v.1.0pre/_demo/file.png"
                        }
                    },
                    // The `folder` type
                    "folder": {
                        // can have files and other folders inside of it, but NOT `drive` nodes
                        "valid_children": ["default", "folder"],
                        "icon": {
                            "image": "http://www.jstree.com/static/v.1.0pre/_demo/folder.png"
                        }
                    },
                    // The `drive` nodes 
                    "drive": {
                        // can have files and folders inside, but NOT other `drive` nodes
                        "valid_children": ["default", "folder"],
                        "icon": {
                            "image": "http://www.jstree.com/static/v.1.0pre/_demo/root.png"
                        },
                        // those prevent the functions with the same name to be used on `drive` nodes
                        // internally the `before` event is used
                        "start_drag": false,
                        "move_node": false,
                        "delete_node": false,
                        "remove": false
                    }
                }
            },
            // UI & core - the nodes to initially select and open will be overwritten by the cookie plugin

            // the UI plugin - it handles selecting/deselecting/hovering nodes
            "ui": {
                // this makes the node with ID node_4 selected onload
                "initially_select": ["node_4"]
            },
            // the core plugin - not many options here
            "core": {
                // just open those two nodes up
                // as this is an AJAX enabled tree, both will be downloaded from the server
                "initially_open": ["node_2", "node_3"]
            }
        })
        .bind("create.jstree", function (e, data) {
            $.post(
                "/backoffice/categorytree/createtreeitem",
                {
                    "id": data.rslt.parent.attr("id").replace("node_", ""),
                    "position": data.rslt.position,
                    "title": data.rslt.name,
                    "type": data.rslt.obj.attr("rel")
                },
                function (r) {
                    if (r.status) {
                        $(data.rslt.obj).attr("id", "node_" + r.id);
                    }
                    else {
                        $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
                    }
                }
            );
        })
        .bind("remove.jstree", function (e, data) {
            data.rslt.obj.each(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/backoffice/categorytree/removetreeitem",
                    data: {
                        "id": this.id.replace("node_", "")
                    },
                    success: function (r) {
                        if (!r.status) {
                            data.inst.refresh();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        })
        .bind("rename.jstree", function (e, data) {
            $.post(
                "/backoffice/categorytree/renametreeitem",
                {
                    "id": data.rslt.obj.attr("id").replace("node_", ""),
                    "title": data.rslt.new_name
                },
                function (r) {
                    if (!r.status) {
                        $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
                    }
                }
            );
        })
        .bind("move_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
            data.rslt.o.each(function (i) {
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/backoffice/categorytree/movetreeitem",
                    data: {
                        "id": $(this).attr("id").replace("node_", ""),
                        "ref": data.rslt.cr === -1 ? 1 : data.rslt.np.attr("id").replace("node_", ""),
                        "position": data.rslt.cp + i,
                        "title": data.rslt.name,
                        "copy": data.rslt.cy ? 1 : 0
                    },
                    success: function (r) {
                        if (!r.status) {
                            $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
                        }
                        else {
                            $(data.rslt.oc).attr("id", "node_" + r.id);
                            if (data.rslt.cy && $(data.rslt.oc).children("UL").length) {
                                data.inst.refresh(data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.oc));
                            }
                        }
                        $("#analyze").click();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because I have add an older version of jquery.hotkeys plugin. After using the file comes with jstree download, the issue has been fixed.